# How to design image compare slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, slider, image-comparison

I want to develop a image compare slider. I have already used 2 very useful packages:
https://pub.dev/packages/before_after
https://pub.dev/packages/image_compare_slider
But there's one issue with them i can't move divider/track out of widget. Track and thumb remains inside the respective widgets. I want to achieve it like this in image. Any solutions for it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I create a package for that, you can use if my package suit your problem
[image_comparator](https://pub.dev/packages/image_comparator)

Comment: can i move control thumb out of image..like you can see on my shared image above. vertical thumb is out of image

Comment: @HadiKhan You can extract and modify my package to suit your design. Code are very simple. My package is not provide your design currently. Sorry

Comment: ok, can you point it out where do i need to make changes in order to move thumb out of widget or give it negative offSet